# MiniZinc: how to sum equal-length subarrays?

Tags: minizinc

The problem I encountered is how to add variables in a[0..9] to b[10..19].
My code is:

```
array[0..19] of int: a=array1d(0..19,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]);
array[0..19] of int: b=array1d(0..19,[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
array[0..9] of var int: c;
constraint
    forall(i in 0..9, j in 10..19)
    (
        c[i]=a[i]+b[j]
    );
solve satisfy;
output[show(c[i]) | i in 0..9];
```

However, MiniZinc gives me the warning "model inconsistency detected, in call 'forall' in array comprehension expressionwith i = 0 with j = 11" and outputs "=====UNSATISFIABLE=====".

How do I get this to work?

Comment: You `forall` loop tries to assign c[i] many times with different values, which is not allowed.  Perhaps you meant addition in parallel loop:  `forall(i in 0..9) ( c[i]=a[i]+b[i+10])`?

Comment: Okay, thank you, it works. Well,  you mean decision variables have a similar feature to parameters (i.e. a parameter can only be given a single value), right?

Comment: Yes, unlike traditional programming languages, in MiniZinc a decision variable cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Extracts the answer from my comments.)

Your `forall` loop tries to assign c[i] many times with different values, which is not allowed. In MiniZinc, unlike traditional programming languages, a decision variables cannot be reassigned.

I guess that you mean addition in a parallel loop:

```
constraint  
  forall(i in 0..9) ( c[i]=a[i]+b[i+10])
;
```